# What is the standard place to keep the Model Matrix?

Tags: opengl, 3d, webgl, direct3d

I have a "3D engine" which has a single model matrix.
All of my 3D objects uses this model matrix (for transformations stuff).
For each object i set the model identity before using it.
So far so great as it appears to be working just fine, and as expected.

But now i am suddenly wondering if i have a design flaw.
Should each 3D object (the base object) have their own model matrix?
Is there any value in doing it this way (model matrix per 3D object)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is literally what the point of the model matrix is. It is an optional transformation for each object you draw from object-space (its local coordinate system) to world-space (a shared coordinate system). You can define your objects such that their positions are already in world-space and then no model matrix is necessary (as you are doing if you use an identity model matrix).

GL uses (or at least historically, it did) a matrix stack for this and it is technically the very reason it uses column-major matrices and post-multiplication. That allows you to push/pop your local coordinate transformations to the ***top*** of the stack immediately before/after you draw an object while leaving the other transformations that rarely change such as world->eye (view matrix) or eye->clip (projection matrix) untouched.

Comment: So, what exactly is the point of the model matrix? And what is your answer to my question?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar: I do not know how to state it any more clearly than that :-\ The model matrix transforms your objects from their own coordinate space into a shared frame of reference. You might have an object centered at (0,0,0) in object-space with vertices from (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1), and you might decide that in ***world-space*** that object is located at (64,32,16). Your model matrix would *translate* all of the coordinates by (64,32,16) and your vertices *after* this transformation would range from (63,31,15) to (65,33,17).

Comment: The model matrix can do a lot more than translate, of course. It can also scale and rotate your objects. But, if you have an identity model matrix then that means that your object's vertices are in world-space (size, position and orientation do not vary per-object).

Comment: Let me ask my question again: Should each object have its own model matrix, or should there be only one model matrix at a higher level (e.g. renderer)?

Comment: Having a single model matrix does not make a lot of sense unless each of your objects belongs to a group of objects with the same transformation. Sort of like if you drew a car as 4 doors, a chassis and 4 tires... when the chassis moves the doors should move with it rather than fall off, as should the tires. However, the tires have an additional transformation that the rest of the car does not - namely, they spin around in addition to moving. So what you might really have in this example is a common model matrix that defines translation, and each of the tires has an extra rotation transform.

Comment: That goes back to the matrix stack I was discussing earlier. You would translate all of the parts of the car together, but when it came time to draw the tires they would have a custom model matrix (rotation) that does not apply to any other part of the car. Technically, the doors might also have their own rotation matrix because they pivot when opened.

Comment: Whoa, I always wondered why the GL used column-major post-multiplication... never realized it was to facilitate push and pop operations!

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating in a separate answer because a comment is too short, but Andon's answer is the right one.

---

#### Think for instance of loading two 3d meshes done from two different artists. ¹

The first artist assumed that 1 unit in your model space is 1 meter, while the other artist assumed 1 inch.

So, you load a car mesh done by the first artist, which maybe is 3 units long; and a banana mesh, which then is 8 units long.

Also, the first artist decided to put the origin of the points for the car mesh in its center, while the artist who did the banana mesh put the banana lying on the X axis, with the base of the fruit on the X=2000 point.

So ***how do you show both of this meshes in your 3d world?*** Are you going to have a banana whose length is almost thrice the length of your car? That makes absolutely no sense.

How are you going to place them next to each other? Or how are you going to place them lying on a plane? The fact that the local coordinate systems are totally random makes it impossible to translate your objects in a coherent way.

#### This is where the model->world matrix comes in.

It allows you to specify a per-model transformation that brings all models into a "shared", unique, coherent space -- the world space.

For instance, you could translate both models so that their origin would lie "in a corner" and all the mesh's vertices in the first octant. Also, if your world space uses "meters", you would need to scale the banana mesh by 0.0254 to bring its size in meters as well. Also, maybe you'd like to rotate the banana and having it lying on the Y axis instead of the X.

At the end of the game, for each "unique model" in your world, you'd have its associated model matrix, and use it when drawing it.

---

Also: for each instance of a model, you could think of applying an extra local trasformation (in world coordinates). For instance, you'd like to translate the car model to a certain point in the world. So instead of having

```
(Model space) --> Model matrix ---> (World space) ---> World matrix ---> (Final world space)
```

you could multiply the two matrices together and having only one matrix that brings points from model space straight to final world space.

---

¹ This point is a bit moot in that in any proper asset pipeline the first thing you'd do would be bringing all the models in a coherent coordinate system, just doing an example...

Comment: I had not considered discussing scaling in the context of converting between units of measure (e.g. meters vs. inches), that is actually a great real-world example even if the modelling software already takes care of that sort of thing..